# How to create border around div element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a border around an element , as soon as , mouse is over it .
I am trying to use:

```
$("body").mouseover(function(e){
    var element =  document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (target.is("div")) {
        element.style.border = "1px solid blue";
        currentElt = target;
    }
    element.onmouseout = function(){
        this.style.border = "0px";
    }
});
```

But what happens, **due to border nearby DOM elements position gets disturbed**.
So, What I am thinking is to create a transparent DIV around that element and on mouse out remove that transparent div.

Please help me with this idea. I am not able to figure out. How to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you use plain CSS? Like `div:hover{border: 1px solid blue}` should do what you want.

Comment: that's one option. Another option is to set the margins or paddings so that the space for the borders is considered.

Comment: The only reason element around move is because the border adds to the element width (well sort of), if when adding your border you reduce your element width by pixel Width * 2 it should be fine.

Comment: @m90: It's a shame, (I only saw your comment now). If you would have posted it as an answer, you could get all the credit for it. Don't post answers as comments!

Comment: @Truth well, technically speaking, it's not an answer to the question :P Never mind.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As the other answers suggest, you can do this using CSS.

> But what happens, due to border , nearing DOM elements position gets
>   disturbed . So , What I am thinking is to create a transparent DIV
>   around that element . and on mouse out. remove that .

In that case, it sounds like you should be [using `outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline) instead of `border`.

```
div:hover {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Xuddz/

Outlines are drawn "above" the element, so no other elements' positions will be disturbed.

Comment: @ManseUK: I ended up using this against the `border` method and still do to this day. Hence upvoting this answer.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a JavaScript/jQuery problem! Use CSS instead!

```
div:hover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

In order to nullify the effect of disturbing the neighboring elements, Use a transparent border around it in the normal state.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use CSS for this, example:

```
div { background: red; border: 1px solid transparent; }
div:hover { border: 1px solid green; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KQzRh/

**UPDATE**

Note that [@thirtydot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138118/how-to-create-border-around-div-element-on-mouseover/10138165#answer-10138193) would be the prefered way, but IE7 doesn't support it (IE6 support niether I think). Then again: it's up to you whether you want to support IE7.

In that case you would do:

```
div:hover { outline: 1px solid green; }
```

Comment: Actually in link you have specified, you have already set up the border with the background color So its not visible initially but when mouse hovers on it, it just changes color. Still thanks for telling me something which i didn't know

Comment: @blunderboy that is a cross-browser way of prevent jumping of the div when suddenly there is a border.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a white/transparent border **equal to width of the border that's going to appear on hover.**

```
.element { border: 1px solid transparent; }
.element:hover { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Comment: I would recommend you'd rather use @thirtydot 's `outline` solution. It is more consistent across different elements, i.e. form elements, div's etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use JS / jQuery you should bind the `mouseover` (i.e. hover) handler to the divs instead of the body (saving you the painful context setting). Like:

```
$('div').hover(function(){
   $(this).css('border','1px solid blue');
},function(){
   $(this).css('border','1px solid transparent');
});
```

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdQ8b/2/)**.

But then again, this could be done in plain CSS as well (which is much better and simpler):

```
div:hover{
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

See **[another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdQ8b/1/)**

If the use of `border` makes your layout jumpy (as border will add to your element's dimensions) you can use `outline` instead (shamelessly stolen from @thirtydot's answer).

Answer (score 1):

This one is simple matter, you can do with css only. Try this one

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">     
  <head>
    <title>Horton Computer Solutions Home</title>
  </head>

  <style type="text/css">
    .some_class:hover{
      color: orange;
      border:2px solid #3300FF;
     }
  </style>
<body>
  <div class="some_class" style="width:290px;"> some text here <br/></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [`box-sizing: border-radius`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) should be mentioned here, even if it's a fairly old question.

If you added used CSS and applied `box-sizing: border-box` to the element, nearby DOM elements position gets disturbed won't get disturbed. Why? Because `box-sizing: border-box` includes the border and the padding as part of the width.

```css
section {  overflow: hidden;  }
div {width: 33.333%; float: left;}

.b-r div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:hover {
  border: 10px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<section class="b-r">
  <strong>These divs have border-radius.</strong><br>
  <div>Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.</div>
  <div>Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.</div>
  <div>Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.</div>
</section>

<section class="nob-r">
  <strong>These divs do not have border-radius.</strong><br>
  <div>Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.</div>
  <div>Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.</div>
  <div>Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.</div>
</section>
```

You could also just use `box-sizing: border-radius` in your example and everything's fixed!

```js
$("body").mouseover(function(e) {
  var element = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  var target = $(e.target);
  if (target.is("div")) {
    element.style.border = "1px solid blue";
    currentElt = target;
  }
  element.onmouseout = function() {
    this.style.border = "0px";
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent Clearfix */
}

div {
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
}

.b-r div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="b-r">
  <strong>These divs have border-radius.</strong><br>
  <div>
    Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.
  </div>

  <div>
    Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.
  </div>

  <div>
    Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.
  </div>
</section>

<section class="nob-r">
  <strong>These divs do not have border-radius.</strong><br>
  <div>
    Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.
  </div>

  <div>
    Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.
  </div>

  <div>
    Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text. Some Text, and more text, and more text, and even more text.
  </div>
</section>
```