# jQuery draw a border in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, real-time

Does anyone know of any plugins which I can use that will gradually draw a border around an element in real time? For example, it would give the impression that someone is actually drawing a border around an element as opposed to just appearing all at once.

Comment: take a look at this, it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138118/how-to-create-border-around-div-element-on-mouseover

Comment: to be clear, you want to animate the drawing? if so, you can use the jquery "animate" method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply top border, right border, bottom border, left border incrementally with 250 ms delay or whatever you'd like.

Comment: (I need to wait another 9 minutes to accept your answer, I haven't forgotten!)

Comment: No worries dude, enjoy the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div id="myelement">
    draw a border around this element
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.border = function() {
    var speed =  1000;
    var borderWidth = 5;
    var $el = $(this);

    $el.css('position','relative');

    var $div = $('<div/>');

    $div.css('position','absolute');
    $div.css('top','-'+borderWidth+'px');
    $div.css('left','-'+borderWidth+'px');
    $div.css('border', borderWidth+'px solid black');
    $div.css('width','0px');
    $div.css('height','0px');
    $div.css('z-index','999');

    $el.append($div);

    $div.animate({
        width: $el.outerWidth() + "px",
        height: $el.outerHeight() + "px"
    }, speed);
};

$('#myelement').border();
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/LSmQC/